# 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Why do we need more moderators?  Are some stepping down?  Has the workload increased?

Comment: @OlinLathrop The site workload isn't so much the issue as much as a decrease in my personal time that I can spend (and I believe this is true of the other mods as well).

Comment: @OlinLathrop I am stepping down. Unless things have changed, moderators dont lose their diamond when they step down unless we become inactive for a long time. I will still be on the site and helping as I can, but as you may have noticed, I have not been as active as I used to be or as I would like to be.

Comment: @Kortuk (and I guess @W5VO): But the other moderators are remaining mods?

Comment: @ChrisLaplante Pretty sure. I just am not able to be on site as much as I used to. In the 30-50 flags per month instead of 100 range.